# Rustで新しい配列を用意せずに、配列内の文字列を全て逆順にできるのか知りたい

Tags: rust

**目標**

- Rustで配列内の文字列を新しい配列を用意せずに、全て逆順にする
- 配列、vectorのどちらでも良い
- 例） `["Hello","World"]` → `["olleH","dlroW"]`

**試したこと**

- for inとiter_mut

```
// data : 反転させたい文字列が格納されている配列
for d in data.iter_mut() {
        *d = d.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
    }
```

エラー
・consider borrowing here: `&d.chars().rev().collect::<String>()`
・mismatched types
expected `&str`, found struct `std::string::String`

エラー文の通りに`&d.chars()...`にしたら`let`を使ってと言われる

- map

```
data = data
        .iter()
        .map(|&d| d.chars().rev().collect::<String>())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

エラー
・mismatched types
expected struct `std::vec::Vec<&str>`
found struct `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`

- そのまま入れるやつ(一応)

```
for (i, d) in data.iter().enumerate() {
        data[i] = &d.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
    }
```

エラー
・cannot assign to `data[_]` because it is borrowed
assignment to borrowed `data[_]` occurs here

Comment: 配列の型を最初からStringにしておくのはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[v..snow さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/88984/3054)にある通り、`String` を使うのが実用的な書き方だと思います。

以下では、`&str`(文字列リテラル)のまま行なう場合を考えます。
この条件だと、「新しい配列を用意せず」の意味合いによって可不可が変わります。

#### 別のメモリ領域を確保したくない、という場合

以下の理由で、これは不可能です。

- `&str` は不変の参照なのでこれを通してデータの変更はできない
- `&str` により参照されている間は、元のデータも変更できない
- 配列の生存期間を終わらせる以外に、参照を「返す」ような操作は無い

特に、文字列リテラルで作られたデータは、読み出し専用メモリ領域に置かれるようなので、unsafe な機能を使っても変更できないと思います。

#### 変換結果の要素を別の配列に入れるのではなく、最初の配列に入れたい、という場合

これは可能です。
必要なのは、

- 変換結果をメモリ領域に保持する
- そのメモリ領域の生存期間を目的の配列以上にする
- 目的の配列の各要素を、確保したメモリ領域への参照とする(借用する)

の3点です。
質問者さんのコードが「`let`を使ってと言われる」のは、上記の生存期間を確保できていないからです。コンパイラの提案に従って `let` を使うと下記のようになり、エラーなく実行可能です。

```rust
let mut data = ["Hello", "World"];
                                                      
let buf0 = data[0].chars().rev().collect::<String>();
let buf1 = data[1].chars().rev().collect::<String>();
data[0] = &buf0;
data[1] = &buf1;
                                                      
dbg!(&data);
assert!(data == ["olleH", "dlroW"]);
```

要素の数だけ `let` を書くのは大変なので、一つの変数にまとめる場合は、下のようなコードが考えられます。

`Vec` を使う例:

```rust
let mut data = ["Hello", "World"];
let mut buf: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
                                                   
for s in data.iter() {
    buf.push(s.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
}
                                                   
for (i, s) in buf.iter().enumerate() {
    data[i] = &s;
}
                                                   
dbg!(&data);
dbg!(&buf);
assert!(data == ["olleH", "dlroW"]);
```

`String` を使う例:

```rust
let mut data = ["Hello", "World"];
let mut buf = String::new();
                                     
for s in data.iter() {
    for c in s.chars().rev() {
        buf.push(c);
    }
}
                                     
let mut head = 0;
for i in 0..data.len() {
    let tail = head + data[i].len();
    data[i] = &buf[head..tail];
    head = tail;
}
                                     
dbg!(&data);
dbg!(&buf);
assert!(data == ["olleH", "dlroW"]);
```

以上のように、コンパイラを満足させるためループが2つに分かれており、いささか非効率かも知れません。もっと良い方法があれば知りたいです。

Answer (score 2):

おそらく全体のコードはこのようになっていると思います

```
fn main() {
    let mut data = ["Hello", "World"];
    for d in data.iter_mut() {
        *d = d.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
    }
    dbg!(&data);    
}
```

この時、`"Hello"`, `data[0]` の型は `&str` であり、`String` とは別のものです。
`&str` は immutable な参照であって、**参照先に**再代入することは出来ません。
よって、元の配列 (or `Vec`) が `&str` の配列である限り、その配列に逆順の文字列を入れることは、（通常の方法では）不可能です

`data` が `String` の配列であれば再代入することが可能です。

```
fn main() {
    let mut data = ["Hello".to_string(), "World".to_string()];
    for d in data.iter_mut() {        
        *d = d.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
    }
    dbg!(&data);    
}
```

Comment: 初学者なりに色々な解釈を考えてみたのですが、この回答は誤りのように感じます。
「immutable な参照であって、参照先に再代入することは出来ません」というは正しいのだと思うのですが、
別の参照を代入することはできますので、「その配列に逆順の文字列を入れることは、（通常の方法では）不可能です」とはならないのではないでしょうか。